# Función en Ajax para cambiar icono

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo una Api que me extrael la temperatura y el estado del clima, cada estado trae un icono con su código, `03d nubes dispersas`, `11d tormenta con mucha lluvia` etc, necesito una función que cada que cambie ese código de icono cambie los iconos que tengo en una carpeta, no se si me hago entender.

Estaba intentando esto así:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>pieza clima</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

       
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                <source src="Videos/viento2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      <div id="contenido">
      <div id="content-text"></div>
      <div id="content-text2"></div>
      <div id="content-text3"></div>
<script>

    var _from = document.location.pathname.split('/'); // Permite obtener la ruta del archivo actual y convertirla en array separados por "/"
    _from = _from[_from.length - 1].replace('.html', '').replace('index_', ''); // filtramos el contenido del array y extraemos el nombre del archivo


     $.ajax({url: "http://digital12.xegmenta.com:3000/weather/api/"+_from,
    success: function(result){
      $("#content-text").html(result.name);
      $("#content-text2").html(result.main.temp);
      $("#content-text3").html(result.weather[0].icon);

if (result.weather[0].icon == "50d") {
  <img src="iconos/Nublado.png" class="img"/>
} else if (condition2) {
  // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is true
} else {
  // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false
}

  }});
    
  </script>
  <h1 class="temperatura">ºC</h1>

  <h1 class="dia"><script>
      var meses = new Array ("enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre");
      var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
      var f=new Date();
      document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + ", " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()]);
      </script></h1>

<h1 class="hora"><span id="liveclock" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;"></span><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function show5(){
 if (!document.layers&&!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
 return
  var Digital=new Date()
  var hours=Digital.getHours()
  var minutes=Digital.getMinutes()
  var seconds=Digital.getSeconds()
  var dn="PM"
 if (hours<12)
 dn="AM"
 if (hours>12)
 hours=hours-12
 if (hours==0)
 hours=12
 if (minutes<=9)
  minutes="0"+minutes
  if (seconds<=9)
  seconds="0"+seconds
 //change font size here to your desire
 myclock="<font size='10' face='Arial' ><b><font size='10'></font></br>"+hours+":"+minutes+":"
  +seconds+" "+dn+"</b></font>"
 if (document.layers){
 document.layers.liveclock.document.write(myclock)
 document.layers.liveclock.document.close()
 }
 else if (document.all)
 liveclock.innerHTML=myclock
 else if (document.getElementById)
 document.getElementById("liveclock").innerHTML=myclock
 setTimeout("show5()",1000)
  }
 window.onload=show5
  </script>
</h1>

<script>
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
//se ejecutara despues de 2 segundos
setTimeout(mostrarTexto, 2000);
//se ejecutara despues de 9 segundos
setTimeout(OcultarTexto, 9000);
function mostrarTexto(){
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","overlay");
}
function OcultarTexto(){
div = document.getElementById('contenido');
div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
}//end function OcultarTexto
</script>
    
        
</body>

</html>
```

Código consola:

```js
{base: "stations", clouds: {…}, cod: 200, coord: {…}, dt: 1551099600, …}
base: "stations"
clouds: {all: 75}
cod: 200
coord: {lat: 3.44, lon: -76.52}
dt: 1551099600
id: 3687925
main: {humidity: 83, pressure: 1017, temp: 22, temp_max: 22, temp_min: 22}
name: "Cali"
sys: {country: "CO", id: 8590, message: 0.0033, sunrise: 1551093471, sunset: 1551136815, …}
visibility: 9000
weather: Array(1)
0: {description: "haze", icon: "50d", id: 721, main: "Haze"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
wind: {speed: 1}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: ¿y no es más cómodo tener todos los iconos, crear una clase con cada una (que se llame igual que el código) y cambiar de clase el elemento desde el mismo ajax? ese es uno de los beneficios de usar css

Comment: Como lo puedo hacer así un ejemplo por favor? @Fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo en plan esquema como se podría abordar el tema que planteas. Como es lógico tendrás de adaptarlo a tu caso concreto y al tipo de estilos que sepas/prefieras usar.

La idea es tener un fichero de estilos con una clase para cada tipo de icono.

**CSS**  (estilos.css)

```
/* establecemos el tamaño mediante id, hace falta un alto y ancho para que se visualice el fondo aunque no tengamos contenido*/ 
#content-text3{
 display:block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;     
}

/* y la imagen dependerá de la clase*/
.fondo_50d{
 background-image: url(images/solazo.png);
}

.fondo_03d{
 background-image: url(images/nubes_dispersas.png);
}

.fondo_11d{
 background-image: url(images/tormenta_lluvia.png);
}
```

El html tendrá una estructura mínima, pues el resto de datos se cargarán por `ajax`.

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <div id="content-text"></div>
   <div id="content-text2"></div>
   <div id="content-text3"></div>
   .....
<div>
```

En dicho ajax se cambiará el contenido y también la clase correspondiente al icono del tiempo.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({url: "http://digital12.xegmenta.com:3000/weather/api/" + _from,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#content-text").html(result.name);
        $("#content-text2").html(result.main.temp);
        $("#content-text3").attr("class", "fondo_" + result.weather[0].icon);
    }
});
```

(editado)

Añado el ejemplo en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1cnxdtv/).

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer todo como me dices, y no me sale nada en el espacio de el content.text @Fly

Comment: `<div id="content-text3" class="fondo_50d"></div>` Así me aparece en consola, como si si se estuviera ejecutando el que es, pero no me sale nada en le content.text y no muestra error @Fly

Comment: `#content-text3` se actualizó correctamente, pues  su `class`  cambió ¿verdad? con lo cual está funcionando, el problema puede ser desde la ruta de la imagen al tamaño de la misma (pasando por infinidad de cuestiones). Debes asegurarte que se ve correctamente aun sin ejecutar el ajax, pon un HTML a mano con valores que conozcas y sepas que se debería ver bien.

Comment: Revisa la ultima edición, miera el ejemplo y asegurate que tu imagen cabe en el alto/ancho establecido en las css.

Comment: Listo amigo, excelente tu ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Amigo tengo una pregunta, necesito hacer lo mismo pero con el video de fondo, lo que pasa es que el video esta afuera de el ajax y yo lo tengo dentro de un contenido que aparece y desaparece, entonces si pongo los videos ahí también se va a desaparecer, como puedo hacer esto por fuera del contenido? @Fly